# puppet mount a loopback device

Tags: mount, fstab, puppet

I was taking **truability** test to assess my skills. I got the below question.

Create a puppet manifest in */root/puppet/lad.pp* to mount the filesystem located in */root/files/LAD/disk.ext2* that:

- will mount the device at "/mnt/LAD"
- sets fstab to prevent the filesystem from being fsck'd and will prevent dump from running on it
- mounts the filesystem as ext2 via loopback device
- mounts the filesystem as read-writable

I just started with puppet and I am not pretty sure if what I have is correct. I have the below file.

```
mount { "/mnt/LAD":
        device  => "/root/files/LAD/disk.ext2",
        fstype  => "ext2",
        ensure  => "mounted",
        options => "-o loop",
    }
```

When I run the above puppet configuration, I get the error as,

```
err: /Stage[main]//Mount[/mnt/LAD]: Could not evaluate: Execution of '/bin/mount -o -o 
loop /mnt/LAD' returned 1: [mntent]: line 13 in /etc/fstab is bad
mount: can't find /mnt/LAD in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab
```

The following option works perfectly fine.

```
mount -o loop /root/files/LAD/disk.ext2 /mnt/LAD
```

Can someone point me where am doing wrong regarding the settings from puppet?

Comment: Try changing `options => "-o loop",` to `options => "loop",`? The error shows `mount -o -o loop` so you'd want to get rid of one of the `-o`s.

Comment: Cool. Glad to be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
options => "-o loop",
```

to

```
options => "loop",
```

The error shows `mount -o -o loop` so you'd want to get rid of one of the `-o` arguments